# AWS API for managing Active Directory

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-directory

My employer wants to integrate our Active Directory with the Amazon elastic cloud service. What api (if any) is appropriate to manage the directory using only java?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Figure out to connect AD with your AWS account.**

There are several options to use Active directory with AWS Services.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/what_is.html#choosing_an_option

- Directory Service for Microsoft Active Directory - Full blown AD managed by AWS.
- AD Connector - AD Proxy to on premise AD
- Simple AD - AWS Managed Samba 4
- Amazon Cloud Directory - Cloud native directory for storing objects
- Amazon cognito - Mobile login user directory.

**2. ES setup with AD**

[This blog post gives more detail](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/secure-your-amazon-elasticsearch-service-domain-with-active-directory-authentication-and-authorization/) But here are the high level steps.

1. Create ES domain
2. Create NGINX proxy
3. Create IAM roles

   Needed input for creating an ES domain
   [image: enter code here]

Create AD user and groups

- AWSESAdmin: This group should contain all the Admin users that need
  full access to the Amazon ES domain.
- AWSESDataLoader: This group
  should contain the users and services that need read-write access to
  the Amazon ES domain.
- AWSESUser: This group should contain the users
  and services that need read-only access to the Amazon ES domain.

All of this available in the Cloudformation template [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-elasticsearch-service-with-authentication/raw/master/elasticsearch_domain_with_auth_proxy.json).

The template gives the following outputs:

1. Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the Amazon ES domain.
2. Private IP URLs for the Amazon ES domain through the proxy. You use these to access the Amazon ES domain.
3. Private IP URLs for the in-built Kibana dashboard through the proxy. You use these for accessing the Kibana dashboard.

[AWS JAVA SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/)